# cosine_similarity giving different answer for dataframe and subset of dataframe

Tags: python, data-science, cosine-similarity

I have the following piece of code for my recommendation system and it gives different output.

Scenario 1:

```
a = df[df.index == 5031]
b = df[df.index == 9365]

print(cosine_similarity(a,b)) #0.33
```

Scenario 2:

```
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(df)

print(cosine_sim[5031][9365]) #0.25
```

I think the output for both scenarios should be the same. I feel scenario 1 to be more accurate according to the data.
Can anyone help with this?

Dataframe looks like this.

Comment: How does your `df` looks like?

Comment: Hi https://i.stack.imgur.com/okwtm.png This is how it looks like @Jamjitul

Comment: Scenario one works with indexes, scenario 2 with positions, those are not always the same.

Comment: @jwzinserl. Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to work with indexes for the whole dataframe?

Comment: Does it make any difference to do df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True) before running both scenarios

Comment: @jwzinserl, Yes it does. It is giving the same output. But the one's that should be similar has cosine value 0 and the one that should not be similar has 1.

Comment: Are you using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`? The output of this will have integer-location based index which may be different than the index from the dataframe.  If you also use the integer-location based index to get the a and b vectors you should get the same result though. `a = df.iloc[5031]` and `b = df.iloc[9365]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing label index with location based index.

In scenario 1 you get the vectors by label index

```
# labels 5031 and 9365
a = df[df.index == 5031]
b = df[df.index == 9365]
```

The matrix which is returned by `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` does not know anything about the index labels.
Thus before you get the data from the matrix you need to know the location based index in the dataframe

```
idx_a = df.index.get_loc(5031)
idx_b = df.index.get_loc(9365)
cosine_sim[idx_a][idx_b]
```